# Regex match entire contents of file in bash

Tags: regex, bash

What is the best way to test if the complete contents of a file matches a regex, such as

```
^[0-9]{9}$
```

i.e., just 9 numbers and nothing else, no line breaks, and not multiple sets of numbers.

Here is one variant I have that I do not really like:

```
cat -vt curloutput.txt | tr "\n" " " | egrep "^[0-9]{9}$"
```

**Edit**

I use the accepted solution like this:

```
grep --perl-regex "(?m)(?<!.)^\d{9}$(?!.)"
```

using GNU grep.

Comment: Do you mean each line of the file having this format or being all the file just this?

Comment: All of the file should be just this.

Comment: Do you want to print the number, filename iff it matches, y/n, or no printing but by exit value?

Comment: I just need the exit value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This regex matches "comprised of 9 digits" and the `(?m)` makes caret and dollar match after/before newlines so it works to prevent multiple lines:

```
(?m)(?<!.)^\d{9}$(?!.)
```

The look arounds wrapping the main match ensure the line matched is the *only* line in the file - ie that there's exactly one line in the file.

See this [demonstrated on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/jlgLZ7zEgM), see how adding any other characters to the 9-digit input text, even a single newline, will result in a non match

Comment: @Bohemian +1 Very nice. Thought there might be a pure regex solution.

Answer (score 6):

Test that the linecount is 1 then test that the line matches the regex:

```
test $(wc -l file.txt | cut -f 1 -d ' ') = 1 \
    && grep -Eq '^[0-9]{9}$' file.txt && echo "match"
```

Breaking down the command, this is what is happening:

```
#get the linecount
wc -l file.txt | cut -f 1 -d ' '

# Check if there is a match in the file
# result will be return value of the program so it can be used 
# directly with the AND operator
grep -Eq '^[0-9]{9}$' file.txt
```

You can be even more restrictive by counting the bytes with wc:

```
test $(wc -c file.txt | cut -f 1 -d ' ') -eq 9
```

Which would catch the trailing newline, if needed. (`-m` will count characters instead, in case you're using multi-byte characters)

Comment: after submitting a quickly whipped (and wrong) answer, I deleted it and I'm upvotting yours : checking that there is 1 line and that lines matches the input takes care of both caveats: no repetitions of the regexp, and that it's actually present (my "solution" deleted the regexp on 1st line only, using a `sed -e '1s/regexp//'`  and checked a 0 byte result, but a 0 byte input file would have also matched those conditions...)

Comment: Instead of `test -n "$MATCH"`, you should just use the grep return value directly: `... && grep -q ...`.

Comment: `wc -l` counts only newlines. Imagine a file with no newlines / only one line and then EOF. `echo -n "123456789" >test ; cat test | wc -l` will print `0`

Comment: @bartimar good point although I made sure to mention the options for `wc -c` and `wc -m` that count bytes and characters respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want no newlines in the file, first check the file size then check the contents:

```
[[ $(stat -c %s $f) -eq 9 && $(<$f) =~ ^[0-9]{9}$ ]] && echo y || echo n
```

testing:

```
$ f=/etc/passwd
$ [[ $(stat -c %s $f) -eq 9 && $(<$f) =~ ^[0-9]{9}$ ]] && echo y || echo n
n

$ f=$(mktemp)
$ printf "123456789" >| $f
$ [[ $(stat -c %s $f) -eq 9 && $(<$f) =~ ^[0-9]{9}$ ]] && echo y || echo n
y
```

Comment: It can be handy, although bash filename expansion patterns are quite powerful too. One thing about bash regexes: do not quote them or else they are treated as plain strings. Can get pretty messy when you're combining variables and regex metachars.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'END{if(NR == 1 && /^[0-9]{9}$/)print}' test.in
```

This prints the number if and only if there is precisely one line and it matches the pattern.

If you just want the return value like `grep -q`, you can use this:

```
awk 'END{exit !(NR == 1 && /^[0-9]{9}$/)}' test.in
```

Comment: Awk seems like the right tool, but I've just tried your two commands and neither seem to work.

Comment: What awk version do you have?

Comment: I have GNU Awk 3.1.7. tried it both with and without newlines

Comment: OK. I have gawk 4. 3.1.7 is 4 years old, you may want to look into upgrading.

Comment: And it's working for me even with the `-P` (POSIX) flag, so I'm not sure what would make an old version not work.

Comment: Hmmm. Will look into it and post reason for failure if I find it.

Comment: Works as expected with gawk 4 Ubuntu machines at work seem to get stuck on 3.1.8 at most, but my home machine with 4.0.1 did the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure test oneliner

```
[[ `cat $file` =~ ^[0-9]{9}$ ]] && exit 0 || exit 1
```